# Fibonacci Heap: Could i always consolidate?

Tags: heaps

Right now I am learning about Fibonacci heaps for the first time.
After the minimum Node of a Fibonacci heap is extracted you consolidate it, to give it a better structure and execute future operations faster.
But why don't you consolidate the Heap more often, like after the insertion of 10 nodes with no consolidation in the meantime?
Is it even possible to Consolidate whenever the heap feels like it? The consolidation would never break the structure, even if it is not executed after the ExtractMin()-Operation, am I right?
Assuming that, I am right why is the consolidation not executed more often? Because it just makes no sense, as it doesn't make it faster or could it make it even slower?

Best regards,
Alex

Comment: Wouldn't it just make everything take more time? like, running the consolidation algorithm takes time by itself, and there is probably no real benefit to use it even more than what it currently is used

Comment: ok, but it would be possible to do it whenever you want, it's just useless?

Comment: If you do it more than necessary then its possible you will hurt the amortized running time. So use it only when necessary

Answer (score 1):

In a Fibonacci heap, `delete-min` takes $O(\log n)$ amortised time, and `insert`, `find-min`, and `decrease-key` all take $O(1)$ amortised time. You could consolidate when you `insert` or `decrease-key`, but then they would take $O(\log n)$ amortised time.

To see why this is an advantage, consider what you would typically use a priority queue with `decrease-key` for, such as shortest path through a graph, or A* search. For each step, you `delete-min` an item, then you process it, then you `insert` or `decrease-key` its successor items.

With a Fibonacci heap, you pay $O(\log n)$ amortised cost per entry that you *process*. The operations that you perform on the *successor* entries have constant-time cost.

Dijkstra's shortest paths algorithm in a case in point. If `insert` and `decrease-key` had $O(\log n)$ cost, then its complexity would be $\Theta((V + E) \log V)$. Using a Fibonacci heap, its complexity is $\Theta(E + V \log V)$.